# Hadoop wordcount on real cluster

Tags: java, hadoop, configuration-files

I'm starting to use Hadoop 2.2 on cluster (after having used it on local). I setup all files:

- hdfs-site.xml
- mapred-site.xml
- yarn-site.xml
- core-site.xml
  the pastes are in the following page http://pastebin.com/u/manLiu

but when I run any task it stops while running the first mapper and rest in pending status.

Clearly, I've removed the real IP addresses and written master and slave. In addition, my cluster is made by 4 nodes but for the simple wordcount im trying to use just one.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just permission problem in the file `hdfs-site.xml`